# Is it all wrong?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix - always quite fake;
>   My suffix - time it does take;
>   My infix - doesn't last long;
>   My whole - is it all wrong?

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could be

> **CONTEMPLATE**

Because

> **CON** - (CONMAN) - always quite fake;
>  **TEMP** - (TEMPORARY) - doesn't last long;
>  **LATE** - (LATE - Example: more time is needed to finish the task) - time it does take;
>  **CONTEMPLATE** - (Wondering about something) - is it all wrong?
>  FIXED: OP says LATE rather than PLATE. Makes sense now :)

Comment: Exactly right! Though I figured just the last four letters for the suffix.