# Is it all wrong, too?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

<sub>*Inspired by  [Is it all wrong?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94440/is-it-all-wrong)*</sub>

> My prefix - maybe ones in need of aid;
>   My suffix - maybe one is someone’s maid;
>   My infix - maybe it’s a part of you;
>   My whole - is it something all wrong, too?

**What am I?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It could be:

> Illegal

My prefix - maybe ones in need of aid;

> **Ill**egal - If you are ill you are in need of aid

My suffix - maybe one is someone’s maid;

> Ille**gal** - A gal could be someones maid?

My infix - maybe it’s a part of you;

> Il**leg**al - A leg is a part of your body.

My whole - is it something all wrong, too?

> If something is illegal it is generally considered wrong.